# Why can't I convert integer as string when reading in dataframe from csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file, which have two columns are integers: count & vote

```
df = pd.read_csv('in.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf8')
...
df.to_csv('out.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

What's strange is that the 'count' column is still integer in out.csv, but the 'vote' becomes floats, i.e. '2.0'. I want to keep it as original integer or str form of numbers, not floats, so I did:

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

But it doesn't help at all. It still outputs floats, but also introduces new nan value for blank cell. How to output integer or str, not floats in the output csv?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example, input and expected output

Comment: It's a regular csv file with several columns. Does it matter for different columns and column vlaues?

Comment: Values on 'vote' column matter. Especially empty values

Comment: They are either 0, 1, or 2 for all rows.

Comment: No nan values at all?

Comment: No. But the column name is: '标签是否准确（1准确；0不准确；2多个标签部分准确'. Maybe it doesn't like the column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just specify a dtype for that column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., dtype={'vote': int}, ...)
```

Or use `str` instead of `int`, it depends on what you need those values for.

Comment: OK. str works for me better. thanks. Why doesn't df = df.applymap(str) work?

Comment: @marlon If you convert a float to a string, the decimal part is not removed. I.e., `2.0` becomes `'2.0'` (and not `'2'`)

Comment: Ok, I see, which means when df reads in the data from csv, it already becomes float, so it's too late to apply the applymap() function.

Comment: @marlon Also please note that when you're saving your Dataframe to a csv file, all your values are automatically converted to strings. So it's completely useless to convert int or floats to str before writing to a csv file. Instead, you might want to convert int to floats or vice versa. Indeed, you will eventually write the string representation of those numbers